# Spring MVC: uploaded file is null if the web app is deployed as a war file in Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

I am using Spring MVC (4.1.3) for my web project. I have the following controller to handle an uploaded file:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/avatar"}, method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String avatarPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
        @RequestParam(value = "uid", required = true) Long uid,
        Map<String, Object> map) {

    try {
        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) multipartRequest.getFile("file");
        String name = file.getOriginalFilename(); //"file" is null if deployed in a war file
        .....

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("upload error");
    }
}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/avatar?uid=1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button name="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

The above code works well in the Eclipse (Luna) plus Jetty (7.x) environment. However, if the web app is deployed in a war file to Tomcat (7.x), the "file" is always null.

What I did is wrong in the above?

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with your whole method and the markup of the form you are submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved. I deployed the same war file onto Tomcat 6.x and the file upload works just fine.

There must be something I dont know about Tomcat 7.x.

Hope this helps someone else.